# Picasa ClientLogin deprecation issues

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, picasa

I have been using the picasa client login for a couple of years without issue.  We use it to store photos that users upload so we do not want to request for user authentication as we are just storing the photos in our own account.  It is developed in .NET.

Up until today it has worked and I can’t work out (and beginning to wander whether it is now possible) how to fix the issue.

Previous Code:

```cs
PicasaService service = new PicasaService("My App");
service.setUserCredentials("myemail@gmail.com", "password");

Uri postUri = new Uri(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("default", AlbumID));
string sContentType = "image/jpeg";

PicasaEntry entry = (PicasaEntry)service.Insert(postUri, fileStream, sContentType, sFilename);

fileStream.Close();

sPicasaURL = entry.Media.Content.Url.ToString();
```

New code using Auth2 (that doesn’t work!)  - I have gone onto the developer console and set up a client ID.  I am using the P12 key in my application generated there to get the access code.

```cs
Uri postUri = new Uri(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("default", AlbumID));

const string ServiceAccountEmail = "email@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("bin/key2.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail)
{
  Scopes = new[] { "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/" }
}.FromCertificate(certificate);

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);

if(!credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.");

var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory(null);
            requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + credential.Token.AccessToken);

PicasaService service = new PicasaService("My App");
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

string sContentType = "image/jpeg";

PicasaEntry entry = (PicasaEntry)service.Insert(postUri, fileStream, sContentType, sFilename);

fileStream.Close();

sPicasaURL = entry.Media.Content.Url.ToString();
```

Can anyone help?

I simply get :

"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." error.
{"Execution of request failed: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/myalbumid"}

Is this type of login even now possible with the clientlogin deprecated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a quick note I have created a service account Client ID in the developers console and this is the one I am using in my application.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue.  I am now getting an access token with Oauth2 but not sure how to use it with the original .NET Google Picasa API, the Google.GData.Photos assembly.

Comment: @kstubs, could you post your code to get the access token please.  I think I have figured out the second part but I am struggling to get the access token.  Are you using a service account or a web application account to get the access token?  I used the outh2 playground to generate a temp access token and was able to use this successfully in my code to post a photo into my picasa album.  I will happily post the complete working code if you can help me out with the first part!  Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded to google for business.  The instructions I was reading suggested that in order to use Service accounts you had to grant domain access to your google drive folders; which is a feature of Google for business.  It's unclear to me that service accounts work as prescribed otherwise.  Additionally, I've moved on from the Picasa .Net api (couldn't find a version supporting OAuth2).

Comment: @kstubs thanks for your reply.  I have tried googling this and can't find this anywhere.  Can you remember where you read this?  A link would be great.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yeah here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation  Scan down the page for this heading: Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account;  read those instructions.  These are specific to a Google business page.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Anyhow, working good for me now.

Comment: I'm using similar code with: PicasaService service = new PicasaService("some-service-name"); service.SetAuthenticationToken(credential.Token.AccessToken); But I get a "Token Invalid" response. 403 Forbidden. I've just signed up for an API free try too.

Comment: Using your code, I can now get a list of Albums, my problem was the headers have changed for OAuth2 from "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={{TOKEN}}" to "Authorization: Bearer {{TOKEN}}". Adding a GDataRequestFactory and custom headers fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the new OAuth2 Authentication Protocol that google enabled 2 days ago.

The ClientLogin API is deprecated and does not work anymore...

I am currently working on solving the same issue and will post my sample Java Code with comments soon.

Cheers,
Gizmo

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will look forward to your code.  I think the Java GData Core library for Java is better than .NET as there appears to be no setOAuth2Credentials available.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked well:

```
public object GetGoogleApiAccessToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string mapPath)
{
    try
    {
        var keyFilePath = mapPath + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyFilePath"];

        // found in developer console
        var serviceAccountEmail = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceAccountEmail"];

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credential =
            new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                //create credential using certificate
            {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait(); //request token

        return credential.Token.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);

        return null;
    }
}
```

HTTP Client Task:

```
private static async Task<string> RunRequest(Uri uri, object token)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    token.ToString());
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("GData-Version", "2");

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return null;

                var jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return jsonStr;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);

                return err.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we use it like this:

```
var urlStr = string.Format("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{0}/albumid/{1}?alt=json",
GoogleUserId, albumID);

var uri = new Uri(urlStr);    

var jsonStr = await RunRequest(uri, accessToken);
```

Answer (score -1):

GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID?deprecation-extension=true

"deprecation-extension": "true"

Comment: I think this is actually meant to be an answer. But the phrasing makes it seem at first glance like a question. Would you like to rephrase to avoid this impression? You could improve by adding more explanation of how it solves the problem. If it actually IS a question, please turn it into an "official" one, by using the "Ask Question" button on the top right of the page, then delete this post.